# Drupal 7 aliases for a certain content type producing 404

Tags: uri, path-aliases

I've got a custom content type ("charity listing").  Nodes in this content type should have the automatic alias charities/view/[name-of-charity].  They do indeed have this alias, when I try to edit a node the alias is there.  However, typing the URL alias into the browser gives me a 404 error.

I have tried re-generating all the automatic URL aliases.  Still doesn't work.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Did you check that the path aliases are pointing to the correct URL? May you show a screenshot showing the editing page for one of those path aliases?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any folder's in your root directory called "charities" or is there any rewrite rule in your.htaccess file? I know it's a long shot, but I had a very similar problem once and this turned out to be the cause.

Also, try putting "?q=" before the alias when you type in the url and see if that works (e.g., http://yourdomain.com/?q=alias/path). it will point to problems related to my other suggestions.